# View não aparece na consulta - Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Tenho um view de 2 campos que não aparece na janela de query. Quando adiciono mais 3 campos, a mesma aparece. O que pode ser?.

View:

```
SELECT        B.TX_LOGIN, COUNT(A.CD_PROCESSO) AS TOTAL
FROM            dbo.TB_DUE_CAPA AS A INNER JOIN
                         dbo.TB_USUARIOS AS B ON A.CD_USUARIO_CRIACAO = B.CD_USUARIO
WHERE        (MONTH(A.DT_PROCESSO) = MONTH(GETDATE())) AND (YEAR(A.DT_PROCESSO) = YEAR(GETDATE()))
GROUP BY B.TX_LOGIN
```

[image: View Criada]

View não aparece na janela:

[image: View não aparece na janela]

Permissões do Usuário:
[image: Permissões do Usuário]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Já tentou clicar com o botão direito em cima da pasta `views` e clicar em recarregar?

Answer (score 0):

> Edit -> IntelliSense -> Refresh Local Cache

Ou o atalho:

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>

Comment: pra aparecer um objeto novo/alterado? um refresh não resolve?

Comment: Sim, esqueci completamente desse detalhe. Editei a pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

Tem certeza que a View já existe?

Para deletar a existente faça:

```
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS Nome_da_View;
```

Para recriar faça:

```
CREATE VIEW Nome_da_View AS  
SELECT B.TX_LOGIN, COUNT(A.CD_PROCESSO) AS TOTAL
FROM   dbo.TB_DUE_CAPA AS A INNER JOIN
       dbo.TB_USUARIOS AS B ON A.CD_USUARIO_CRIACAO = B.CD_USUARIO
WHERE  (MONTH(A.DT_PROCESSO) = MONTH(GETDATE())) AND (YEAR(A.DT_PROCESSO) = YEAR(GETDATE()))
GROUP BY B.TX_LOGIN;
```

Verifique as permissões de visualizações dos objetos do banco, pois pode ser que você n~]ao tenha.

Verifique também o que o @Lockzera falou, pois não me surpreenderia se isso acontece com o windows mesmo...

Comment: Já tentei isso, mas continua na mesma. Vou incluir imagem das permissões do usuário do sql server

Answer (score -1):

Existe um Bug no SQL Server quando o windows 10 'suspende a atividade'( quando fica muito tempo sem sem mexer e acaba hibernando) o sql server buga, basta reiniciar a maquina.

Comment: reiniciar o servidor SQL? que solução é essa? onde está documentado esse suposto bug?

Comment: reiniciar a maquina que está com o sql server, onde está documentado eu não sei kkkk, mas acontece muito esse bug, tanto com a viwers quanto a qualquer outra criação que voce fizer, elas são feitas porem nao é mostrada no navegação do lado esquerdo, é bug do windows 10

Comment: entendo o que vc quer dizer, mas veja que na pergunta nem fala que é windows 10, e se estiver acontecendo no windows server? o que quero dizer é que ficou muito inconclusiva a resposta